# Responding to REQUEST_METHOD = HEAD using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC site and ELMAH is showing me that my site is erroring when receiving an HTTP request with REQUEST_METHOD = HEAD.

How do I respond to these requests using ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `[AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Head )]` attribute to mark the method as responding to a HEAD request.  You can add more potential methods by OR'ing the verbs together so it can respond to multiple request verbs. I suspect your method is already marked with the attribute as I think it should respond to any request verb if you don't have any restrictions. On a side note, I think it would be pretty rare to get a HEAD request, care to elaborate on why and how you're receiving it?

Comment: Thanks.  My home controller's index method is the one being hit with the HEAD request.  It's currently set up with an AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.GET).  I guess I'll need to add an HttpVerbs.Head to that as well.  As for why I'm receiving the request, I wish I knew more myself.  All I know is that I periodically get an error e-mail from ELMAH saying "A public action method 'Index' could not be found on controller 'Web.Controllers.HomeController'".  The details show that the REQUEST_METHOD is HEAD. I don't recognize the IP address the request comes from. Maybe a spider/crawler?

Comment: I wouldn't add the verb unless **your code** is what is making the request.  It may be that you want to respond to this request, but I would expect most spider/crawlers would be doing a full GET.  FWIW, I don't see these when Google crawls my sites.

Comment: I get this from web spiders too. Its a pain in the ass.